# Using RSpec subject to setup a test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I find myself using subject blocks in my tests to setup example because it is succinct. However is this considered bad form and can it have undesired  consequences?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "stations/index" do


  before(:each) do
    stub_user_for_view_test
    assign(:stations, [
      stub_model(Station),
      stub_model(Station)
    ])

  end

  context "when not an admin" do
    subject {
      render
      rendered
    }

    it { should match /[s|S]tations/ }
    it { should have_selector('.station', :minimum => 2) }
    it { should_not have_link 'Edit' }
    it { should_not have_link 'Delete' }
  end

  context "when an admin" do

    subject {
      @ability.can :manage, Station
      render
      rendered
    }

    it { should have_link 'Edit' }
    it { should have_link 'Delete' }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no unintended consequences, but it is a little unusual and may surprise the reader.  However, it is a small surprise.

It usually communicates intent well to use `subject` to declare the subject, and `before` to setup preconditions unrelated to the subject.  For preconditions that involve the subject, those are often better in a `before` block as well, but it's not too surprising to find them in the `subject` block.

So, instead of this:

```
subject {
  @ability.can :manage, Station
  render
  rendered
}
```

this:

```
before(:each) do
  @ability.can :manage, Station
  render
end

subject {rendered}
```

I used `do...end` for the multi line block and `{}` for the single line block; this is a common (although not ubiquitous) practice.